# How is the news.vice.com search box positioned? (URL inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, user-interface

https://news.vice.com/

I'm asking about the little magnifying glass. Look at the page with browser window < 800px wide and you'll see that the icon, when clicked, expands to the left, animating OVER any navigation buttons that are nearby.

Is the searchbox probably positioned absolutely?  If so, how is it positioned exactly where it needs to be? I've built a version that works, but I've had to manually adjust the element's top and right position pixel by pixel and it's pretty brittle (ctrl-plus breaks the layout).

I'm thinking I could measure the other elements with javascript and use that to position the searchbox on load/resize but that seems inelegant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you inspect the element to see what they are doing?

Comment: I did. Sort of. According to chrome dev tools, the search box *is* absolutely positioned. But I still don't know how that absolute position is calculated. Assuming javascript, but having a hard time shuffling through their minified .js files.

Comment: Those of us reading the question would also have a hard time browsing through their files and what you have asked (*"Any ideas?"*) is not really on topic for SO. Can you rework your question, perhaps show us what you did and what you expect then have us help you make yours less brittle?

Comment: That's why I tried to leave code out of it. I don't want to copy *how* vice does things. I want to duplicate *what* their code does. But my phrasing might have been vague. I'll try to rephrase: is there a clever way to place an absolutely positioned element relative to its *siblings* and not its parent? Siblings who should be assumed dynamically sized. In this case, set the form/input box directly to the left of the next element. My plan is javascript--or maybe setting all relevant elements with px instead of em, but I'm hoping for something better.